# Multiplying two variable names on mac os

Tags: c, macos, gcc, multiplication

I am trying to have a c program work in my mac partition and have figured most of the way to do it but cannot figure out a very simple problem.

so i have a .h file where i declare all my variables and in my .c file i am trying to run a command like

```
L2toL1 = (L2_transfer_time)*(L1_block_size);
```

However i never get the correct answer. i print the variables before the line above and they print correctly but the answer when there are multiplied together is way off. So how can i accomplishes the correct multiplication?

The .h file looks like

```
#define CONFIG_PARAM 16
#define HIT 1
#define MISS 0
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

unsigned long long L2=0;
unsigned long long L1=0;

int L1_block_size=0;
int L1_cache_size=0;
int L1_assoc=0;
int L1_hit_time=0;
int L1_miss_time=0;
int L2_block_size=0;
int L2_cache_size=0;
int L2_assoc=0;
int L2_hit_time=0;
extern int L2_miss_time=0;
int L2_transfer_time=0;
int L2_bus_width=0;
int mem_sendaddr=0;
int mem_ready=0;
int mem_chunktime=0;
int mem_chunksize=0;
unsigned long long test;
```

The .c file is then running the following and reads in specific values from a config file
the answer to the print f statement should be 195 but its like 49567

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "definitions.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *config_file, *trace;
    unsigned int address, exec_info;
    char check, trash[25], op;
    int j, para;
    int i=0;

    if(argc >= 2)   
    config_file = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    else 
    config_file = fopen("config0.txt","r");

// Grabs desired cache parameters from the specified config files
while(fscanf(config_file,"%s %d\n",trash,&para) == 2) {
config[i] = para;
i++;      
}

// Close the config file
fclose(config_file);

// Puts Cache parameters from config file in desired variables
InitializeParameters();

/*
unsigned long long L2toL1;
L2toL1 = (L2_miss_time)*(L1_block_size);
printf("L2toL1 is: %Lu\n",L2toL1);

}

int InitializeParameters() {   
L1_cache_size = config[0];
L1_block_size = config[1];
L1_assoc = config[2];
L1_hit_time = config[3];
L1_miss_time = config[4];
L2_block_size = config[5];
L2_cache_size = config[6];
L2_assoc = config[7];
L2_hit_time = config[8];
L2_miss_time = config[9];
L2_transfer_time = config[10];
L2_bus_width = config[11];
mem_sendaddr=config[12];
mem_ready=config[13];
mem_chunktime=config[14];
mem_chunksize=config[15];    
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What are the inputs?; and what outputs you are getting?

Comment: Please show a complete example (including the complete definitions of all the variables, and the print statements, and the values that you're using).

Comment: What are the values? Are you sure there isn't an overflow going on?

Comment: Your `config` array is used in two places, but not defined *anywhere*?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting weird numbers because your result does not fit on the destination variable. Example: you are multiplying two numbers that are so big that don't fit on the destination memory location.

Example, if you have this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int a, b, c;
   a = 2000000000;
   b = 2000000000;
   c = a*b;
   printf ("%d x %d = %d", a, b, c);
   return 0;
}
```

Will print:

```
 2000000000 x 2000000000 = -1651507200
```

Having said this, it's not a good idea to declare your variables on header files.

Comment: this cannot be the case the numbers being multiply are 32 and 6

Answer (score 0):

You are using `%Lu` in your printf format string. I think `L` only applies to `long double` types, not `long long int` types.

You should use `%llu` like this:

```
printf("L2toL1 is: %llu\n",L2toL1);
```

Of course, it depends what C library you are using: not all are properly standards compliant, and your's may use something else.